# sort by word length in Nth column

Tags: bash, sorting, gnu

I've got a column file like this:

```
1 1 1 AKSDFJADFKASDJFAK
2 1 1 ADKLCJASDLKCJDLACKADCJLKDACJADS
3 1 2 AKLJDFHALKDJFHLKJSDKSDFHAKJFDHAKFHJAKFJ
```

And I would like to sort the entries by the fourth column, with the **longest** word first. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{print $0" "length($4)}' infile | sort -k5,5rn | sed -e 's/ [0-9]*$//' > outfile
```